# Passing jquery mobile theme value to div tag with backbone

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, backbone.js, themes

I want to be able to change my theme will the app is running. How I can pass the value back from backbone, but can't figure how to add it to the page div. For example, in the following code {{-theme}} is replaced by the actual value, say a.

```
   -- <div data-role="page" id="todopage" >
    --  <div data-theme="a" id="testr">{{-theme}}</span>
```

I want to be able to do some thing like this

```
          <div data-role="page" id="todopage" data-theme="<%{{-theme}} %>">
```

. Is this possible?

I'm getting the value to theme, bu using the following code

```
  self.setElement('#todopage')

  self.elem = {
      testr: self.$el.find('#testr')

 }
  self.tm = {
      testr: _.template( self.elem.testr.html() )
 }
```

and in the render
     var loaded = app.model.state.get('theme')

```
  self.elem.testr.html( self.tm.testr({
      theme: loaded 
  }) )
```

I'm not sure now to pass the value directly back to the div tag. Has anyone any ideas?

thanks
mark

Comment: I have tried using   $("#todopage").attr("data-theme", "e")
       $("#todopage").attr("data-content-theme","e"), which does pass the values to the element when I inspect it. this is the inspected code <div data-role="page" id="todopage" data-url="todopage" tabindex="0" class="ui-page ui-body-c ui-page-header-fixed ui-page-active" style="min-height: 113px; padding-top: 43px; " data-theme="e" data-content-theme="e">

However the theme does not get set

Answer (score 0):

Got it working using 
       $("#todopage").attr("data-theme", loaded) 
       $("#todopage").attr("data-content-theme",loaded)
        $('#todopage').page('destroy').page();